# Graphing Polar Curves?

Tags: calculus

So recently I ran into this problem, and I was very much stuck at the sight of it. I was wondering if there is an easy way to depict the polar curve of a specific function without necessarily having to graph points. Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

We have $\displaystyle r=-\csc(t)=-\frac{1}{\sin(t)}$.

We multiply both sides by $\sin(t)$ to get $r\sin(t)=-1$.

By definition of polar coordinates, we have $r\sin(t)=y$.

So this graph in polar coordinates corresponds to $y=-1$, or option (B).

Comment: yep, simple and effective explanation.